# Spring MVC - Trouble with AJAX form posting

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, spring

I'm having a trouble when posting a form with AJAX.

Here is my ajax call:

```
function submit() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/executeRetrieve",
            data: $("#form").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        })
    }
```

And here is my HTML form (They're in the same page):

```
<form id="form" method="post">
User <input type="text" name="user" id="user"/><br />
Password <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submit()"/>
```

And also, this is my action:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/executeRetrieve", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public @ResponseBody String executeRetrieve(HttpServletRequest request) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("message", "hello");

    return json.toString();
}
```

I'm confused. Shouldn't that work? I've been searching for a solution for at least 3 days and I can't get to understand what's happening. The action method isn't even being reached. Would someone know where I am making a mistake?

Thanks in advance, pals.

Comment: is there any network traffic?

Comment: @BevynQ I'm sorry?

Comment: use chrome, inspect an element click network. Then try and fire your event. You should see some network traffic. In particular a post.

Comment: Oh, I got it. That's what is shown on the network tab: `http://localhost:8080/`. Thanks in advance, @BevynQ !

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis @BevynQ It's all successfull. I suppose AJAX is not working. I have set the `preventDefault()` element on the scope of the function, but it posts normally to the action and shows me the response body

Answer (score 0):

I think there is issue in URI that you are trying to call from ajax http://localhost:8080/executeRetrieve. It should contains the application name deployed in server as well. e.g. `http://localhost:8080/<app_name>/executeRetrieve`

Comment: Tried this. Had no success :(